# Riak 1.3.1 will not start on lucid, Ec2 instance

Tags: riak

I have installed riak (apt-get) on an EC2 instance, lucid, amd64 with libssl.

When running riak start I get:

```
Attempting to restart script through sudo -H -u riak
Riak failed to start within 15 seconds,
see the output of 'riak console' for more information.
If you want to wait longer, set the environment variable
WAIT_FOR_ERLANG to the number of seconds to wait.
```

Running riak console:

```
Exec: /usr/lib/riak/erts-5.9.1/bin/erlexec -boot /usr/lib/riak/releases/1.3.1/riak
-embedded -config /etc/riak/app.config
-pa /usr/lib/riak/lib/basho-patches
-args_file /etc/riak/vm.args -- console

Root: /usr/lib/riak

Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:64] [kernel-poll:true]

/usr/lib/riak/lib/os_mon-2.2.9/priv/bin/memsup: Erlang has closed. 

Erlang has closed
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,riak_core,     {shutdown,{riak_core_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}

Crash dump was written to: /var/log/riak/erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,riak_core,   {shutdown,{riak_core_app,start,[normal,[]]}}})
```

The error logs:

```
2013-04-24 11:36:20.897 [error] <0.146.0> CRASH REPORT Process riak_core_handoff_listener with 1 neighbours exited with reason: bad return value: {error,eaddrinuse} in    gen_server:init_it/6 line 332
2013-04-24 11:36:20.899 [error] <0.145.0> Supervisor riak_core_handoff_listener_sup had   child riak_core_handoff_listener started with riak_core_handoff_listener:start_link() at undefined exit with reason bad return value: {error,eaddrinuse} in context start_error
2013-04-24 11:36:20.902 [error] <0.142.0> Supervisor riak_core_handoff_sup had child riak_core_handoff_listener_sup started with riak_core_handoff_listener_sup:start_link() at undefined exit with reason shutdown in context start_error

2013-04-24 11:36:20.903 [error] <0.130.0> Supervisor riak_core_sup had child riak_core_handoff_sup started with riak_core_handoff_sup:start_link() at undefined exit with reason shutdown in context start_error
```

I'm new to Riak and basically tried to run through the "Fast Track" docs.

None of the default core IP settings in the configs have been changed. They are still set to {http, [ {"127.0.0.1", 8098 } ]}, {handoff_port, 8099 }

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error log seems to indicate that something is already running on the handoff port. Have you verified that the ports are not in use before starting, e.g. through 'netstat -a | grep LISTEN | grep 80'?

Comment: Could you also check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359656/riak-map-reduce-in-js-returning-limited-data

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but there is some solid documentation about the errors in the `crash.dump` file on the [Riak site](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/running/recovery/errors/).