# Riak Map Reduce in JS returning limited data

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, riak

So I have `Riak` running on 2 `EC2` servers, using python to run javascript `Mapreduce`. They have been clustered. Mainly used for "proof of concept".

There are 50 keys in the bucket, all the map/reduce function does is re-format the data. This is only for testing the map/reduce functionality in Riak.

> Problem: The output only shows [{u'e': 2, u'undefined': 2, u'w': 2}].
>   That is completely wrong. The logs show that all the keys have
>   "processed" but only 2 get returned. So my question is why is that
>   happening and am I missing something important.

Code:

```
import riak
client = riak.RiakClient()
query = riak.RiakMapReduce(client).add('raw_hits10')
query.map("""function(v) {
      var data = JSON.parse(v.values[0].data);
      return [[data, 1]];
}""")
query.reduce("""function(vk) {
         var res = {};
         for (var indx in vk) {
            var key_t = vk[indx][0];
            var val_t = vk[indx][1];
            ejsLog('/tmp/map_reduce.log', key_t + "--- " + val_t);

            res[key_t] = 2;
         }
         return [res]
    }
      """)


for res in query.run():
    print res
```

The results from printing:

```
[{u'e': 2, u'undefined': 2, u'w': 2}]
```

This makes no sense

Comment: The logs seem to indicate that only 20 items get "reduced" at a time. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to avoid having to load all data from the preceding phase into memory on the coordinating node before running the reduce phase (which would be problematic for large mapreduce jobs), the reduce function is run multiple times. Every iteration gets a batch of results from preceding phase together with any output from earlier reduce phase iteration(s). The default batch size is 20, but this is [configurable](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/references/appendices/MapReduce-Implementation/#Configuration-Tuning-for-Reduce-Phases). As the results from one reduce phase iteration will be fed in as input to the next iteration, reduce phase functions need to designed to handle this, [and some strategies are described here](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/references/appendices/MapReduce-Implementation/#How-a-Reduce-Phase-Works-in-Riak).

It is also possible to force Riak to only run the reduce phase once for the entire input set by specifying the 'reduce_phase_only_1' parameter, but this is generally not recommended, especially for large jobs.

Comment: Thanks... Do you have an example of "the reduce function is run multiple times" in python and JS. This is still a bit confusing.

Comment: As the input to your reduce phase function may contain a mix of map phase values and previous reduce phase output, you can't assume that all values passed into the reduce function come from the preceding map phase unless the input format is the same as the output format in the reduce phase, e.g. numbers to be summed up. Otherwise you will need to look at each value and determine if it comes from a map pahse or not before processing it.

Comment: Thanks @christian-dahlqvist. Is there an actual code example? It would be helpful to see it put into practice.

Comment: Thanks so much @christian-dahlqvist. I have been struggling with incorrect data in my reduce function all day. My test case was only using 20 items so I only saw the error in production code.